# How to add aggregate values in Django Rest Framework ModelViewSets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my DRF app I have the following model, serializer and view.

models.py

```
class Log(models.Model):
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    water_consumption = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    elec_consumption = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

serializers.py

```
class ConsumptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ("water_consumption", "elec_consumption")
```

views.py

```
class ConsumptionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = ConsumptionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Get params from url
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        # Make sure params are not null
        if start_date is not None and end_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date_time__range=[start_date, end_date])
            return queryset
        else:
            raise ValidationError({"ERROR": ["No params found in url"]})
```

This works and it outputs something like this in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    },
    {
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    },
    {
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    },
]
```

What I would like to achieve is to receive some aggregated data alongside those data, like this:

```
{
    "total_water_consumption": 3,
    "total_elec_consumption": 3,
    "detailed_logs": [{
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    },
    {
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    },
    {
        "water_consumption": 1,
        "electrical_consumption": 1
    }]
}
```

How should I customise the queryset to have the total values added?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `SerializerMethodField` in your serializer file

Docs in : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

And you can access `request` in serializer as `context`:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum


class ConsumptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_water_consumption = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_elec_consumption = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ("water_consumption", "elec_consumption")

    def get_total_water_consumption(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        query_params = request.query_params.get(...)
        return Log.objects.filter(...).aggregate(Sum('water_consumption')).get('water_consumption__sum')

    def get_total_elec_consumption(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        query_params = request.query_params.get(...)
        return Log.objects.filter(...).aggregate(Sum('elec_consumption')).get('elec_consumption__sum')
```

Comment: Hello @Amin, I had tried this but it didn't work because the filter depends on parameters taken from the url each time the request is made, so how can those be passed to the serializer?

Comment: I've updated answer for you @Giulia

Comment: thank you very much, it makes sense and I got it working. Only, this way it adds the aggregated field in all the logs, would it be possible to have it added only once in the response, followed by the logs?

Comment: You can use nested serializer for that. have a serializer with these two aggregate fields, and one field called `logs` for example which is nested with your prior serializer. then pass your items as `logs` keyword to serializer ... @Giulia

Comment: Or u can override `to_represention()` method in your serializer. Or attach these aggregate fields to your final prior result in `views` @Giulia